# Register views with regions depending on the user rights

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a TabControl as an ItemControl hosting a region, let's call it ContentRegion. Several modules register at least one view into the ContentRegion. But these registrations are made during module initialization.

I want to prohibit the registration of several views depending on the current user. But the user logs on after the module initialization and also can change during runtime.

Is there a way to provide a callback where prism can evaluate if the registration is active? Or do I have the chance to disable registrations of the region manager? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: Implement a custom region behaviour. You just have to derive from the existing AutoPopulateRegionBehaviour:

```
public class SecurityEnabledAutoPopulateRegionBehaviour : AutoPopulateRegionBehavior
{
    IUnityContainer container;

    public SecurityEnabledAutoPopulateRegionBehaviour(IUnityContainer container, IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry)
        :base(regionViewRegistry)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    protected override void AddViewIntoRegion(object viewToAdd)
    {
        IRequiredAccessRight viewPermission = viewToAdd as IRequiredAccessRight;
        if ( viewPermission != null )
        {
            ISessionManager sessionManager = container.Resolve<ISessionManager>( );
            if ( sessionManager.AccessRights.IsGranted( viewPermission.RequiredAccessRight ) )
            {
                this.Region.Add( viewToAdd );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.Region.Add( viewToAdd ); //The region does not require any permissions so we can proceed
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to override all AutoPopulateRegionBehaviours or only on specific regions. How to achieve this is described in Appendix E of the Prism documentation in detail. What i did was to attach the behaviour only to a specific region and replace the AutoPopulateRegionBehaviour:

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MainView( IUnityContainer container ) 
    {
        InitializeComponent( );

        ObservableObject<IRegion> observableRegion = RegionManager.GetObservableRegion( ControlHostingTheRegion );

        observableRegion.PropertyChanged += ( sender, args ) =>
        {
            IRegion region = ( (ObservableObject<IRegion>)sender ).Value;
            region.Behaviors.Add( AutoPopulateRegionBehavior.BehaviorKey,
                (SecurityEnabledAutoPopulateRegionBehaviour)container.Resolve( typeof( SecurityEnabledAutoPopulateRegionBehaviour ) ) );
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `TabItem.Visibility` to a variable that indicates if it should be shown or not. Once you checked the user rights, set this variable so that it hides unwanted tabs.

Another possibility would be to add the views to the regions after you checked the user rights, instead of registering the views with the regions.

```
IRegion detailsRegion = regionManager.Regions["DetailsRegion"];
detailsRegion.Add(view, viewName);
detailsRegion.Activate(view); // not sure if you need the Activate
```

Comment: The second approach is against the modularity principal. The views register into the region because of no component knowing each view and thus no component can trigger each after the initialization to to add (or not) itself into a region.